# Tensorflow Weights Diverge or NaN

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying out tensorflow for the first time by implementing a simple linear regression. Instead of converging, my weights diverge to infinity in a few iterations.

First I initialize my data

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
T = 100
noise = 10*np.random.random(size=T).astype(np.float32)
x = np.array([np.arange(T), np.ones(T)]).astype(np.float32)
w = np.array([[2,4]]).astype(np.float32)
y = w.dot(x) + noise
w.dot(x)
```

then I create my tensorflow variables:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, T], name="X")
W = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1,2]), name="W")
Yhat = tf.matmul(W,X)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1,T], name="Y")
MSE = (1./(2*T))*tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(Y-Yhat, 2))
```

I then train the model

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
trainer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(MSE)
for _ in range(100):
    sess.run(trainer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
    print sess.run(MSE,feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
```

And I get the output

```
5.55387e+09
1.49582e+16
4.02866e+22
1.08503e+29
2.9223e+35
inf
inf
inf
inf
inf
inf
nan
nan
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your learning rate is probably too high such that the optimiser cannot descend to the minimum but rather jumps around in the parameter space. Try with a learning rate such as `1e-3`.

Comment: I'm still getting NaNs

Comment: Yes that is the case. So really linear regression is highly dependent on the manual tweaking of a learning rate. My professor calls this grad student descent.

Answer (score 2):

The weight diverge and grow to NaN (Inf) because the learning rate is too high (0.5). I have tesed your code and set learning rate to 0.0005, the network can work.
There's another way to handle the learning rate problem, try use AdamOptimizer instead of GradientDescentOptimizer if you are not sure which learning rate is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you see your loss increasing or see NaN during training, always first check your learning rate!

If you still have problems you could also see what the values of the gradients are while training!

Comment: He wrote that he checked his learning rate and even with 1e-5 he still has the same problem. So your answer does not help.